# in select query when use column name it is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query in sql server 2012

```
select *  
from (select a.AccountNo, a.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AccountDesc,
        a.AccountNo + ' '+ a.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AccountTitle, 
        SUM(h.Debit) Debit, SUM(h.Credit) Credit,
        SUM(h.Debit-h.Credit) Remain   
      FROM TblAuxiliary a 
          JOIN ViwDocHeaderItem h ON a.AccountNo = h.AccountNo 
      WHERE  h.DocDate>='01/01/2016'
         AND h.DocDate<='08/30/2016' 
         AND SUBSTRING(h.AccountNo,1,2)='11'
      GROUP BY a.AccountNo, a.AuxiliaryLatinDesc) t1   
    Full join  
     (SELECT a.AccountNo, a.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AccountDesc, 
          a.AccountNo + ' '+ a.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AccountTitle, 
      SUM(h.Debit) Debit, SUM(h.Credit) Credit, 
              SUM(h.Debit-h.Credit) opening 
      FROM TblAuxiliary a JOIN ViwDocHeaderItem h 
         ON a.AccountNo = h.AccountNo  
      WHERE h.DocDate between '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2016'    
          AND SUBSTRING(h.AccountNo,1,2)='11' 
      GROUP BY   a.AccountNo, a.AuxiliaryLatinDesc) t2 
on  t1.AccountNo=t2.AccountNo 
ORDER BY t1.AccountNo
```

it is very fast . but when i replace * by column names  like this :

```
select t2.AccountNo  from (sELECT     TblAuxiliary.AccountNo     , TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountDesc,TblAuxiliary.AccountNo + ' '+TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountTitle
     , SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit) AS Debit, SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS Credit,SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit-ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS Remain     
     FROM TblAuxiliary INNER JOIN ViwDocHeaderItem ON TblAuxiliary.AccountNo = ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo WHERE  ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate>='01/01/2016' AND ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate<='08/30/2016' AND SUBSTRING(ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo,1,2)='11'      
      GROUP BY TblAuxiliary.AccountNo, TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc  ) t1   Full outer join  
        (SELECT TblAuxiliary.AccountNo, TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountDesc,TblAuxiliary.AccountNo + ' '+TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountTitle, 
      SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit) AS Debit, SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS Credit,SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit-ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS opening 
       FROM TblAuxiliary INNER JOIN ViwDocHeaderItem ON TblAuxiliary.AccountNo = ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo  WHERE ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate>='01/01/2000'  AND ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate<'01/01/2016'    AND SUBSTRING(ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo,1,2)='11' 
        GROUP BY   TblAuxiliary.AccountNo, TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc) t2 on  t1.AccountNo=t2.AccountNo ORDER BY t1.AccountNo
```

it 'll be very slow . how can i fix it?

Comment: Generate execution plans. Compare them. Consider the differences between them. These are things you can do but we cannot.

Comment: Is AccountNo column have index ? , try creating index , also your query is not good , you have more sub queries which becomes table as a resultset, it is not good practice , if you can do that in joining tables without sub queries , that is much better.

Comment: As Damien suggested, check execution plans. There may be a poorly considered index wreaking havoc in there somewhere

Comment: @Japongskie  i want to select 5 columns not only accountno

Answer (score 0):

Can you make try with the below query.

```
;WITH cte_1
 AS
    (SELECT  TblAuxiliary.AccountNo , TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountDesc,TblAuxiliary.AccountNo + ' '+TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountTitle
             ,SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit) AS Debit, SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS Credit,SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit-ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS Remain     
     FROM TblAuxiliary 
       INNER JOIN ViwDocHeaderItem ON TblAuxiliary.AccountNo = ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo 
     WHERE  ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate>='01/01/2016' AND ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate<='08/30/2016' AND SUBSTRING(ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo,1,2)='11'      
      GROUP BY TblAuxiliary.AccountNo, TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc  ) 
,cte_2
  AS (SELECT TblAuxiliary.AccountNo, TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountDesc,TblAuxiliary.AccountNo + ' '+TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc AS AccountTitle 
             ,SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit) AS Debit, SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS Credit,SUM(ViwDocHeaderItem.Debit-ViwDocHeaderItem.Credit) AS opening 
      FROM TblAuxiliary INNER JOIN ViwDocHeaderItem ON TblAuxiliary.AccountNo = ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo  WHERE ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate>='01/01/2000'  AND ViwDocHeaderItem.DocDate<'01/01/2016'    AND SUBSTRING(ViwDocHeaderItem.AccountNo,1,2)='11' 
      GROUP BY   TblAuxiliary.AccountNo, TblAuxiliary.AuxiliaryLatinDesc) 
SELECT t2.AccountNo
FROM  cte_1 t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN cte_2 t2  ON  t1.AccountNo=t2.AccountNo 
ORDER BY t1.AccountNo
```

Comment: i want full join . when i user right join it is very fast , but my problem in full join

Comment: did you tried the above script with full out join..?

Comment: can you create a non clustered index on the AccountNo and try it again..

Comment: when i use only accountno in select it is very slow. but when i use some columns in select is is very fast. i dont know why this happen?

Comment: Run your query and check with your execution plan.. Let me know if there any scan operation in the plan